# Laravel - 2xHasMany Relations one other Table

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have table `Messages`

with columns `from` and `to`

That corresponds to some users in table Users.

So I need something like (hasMany relationship in Users model - hasMany messages)

```
public function Messages()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Messages', 'from', 'id');
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Messages', 'to', 'id');
    }
```

But there are two returns, and the second one is an Unreachable statement.
So how to manage many relations when there is more many than one?

Answer (score 3):

Create a second relation:

```
public function messageRetrieved()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Messages', 'from', 'id');
}

public function messageSend()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Messages', 'to', 'id');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First you cannot use 2 return like this

```
public function Messages()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Messages', 'from', 'id');
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Messages', 'to', 'id');
}
```

It will better if you separate it to 2 method like this:

```
public function to()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Messages', 'to', 'id');
}

public function from()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Messages', 'from', 'id');
}
```